# Es posible capturar el nombre del Stored Procedure que hace un INSERT, UPDATE o DELETE a una tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, trigger

estuve investigando sobre los Triggers en Sql server y puede hacer una acción cuando a una tabla se le hizo un UPDATE.

Hasta ahí todo bien. Quise hacer algo mas avanzado pero no consigo dentro de las definiciones si es posible o no se si lo he estado buscando mal.

Es posible que dentro de un trigger luego de que en una tabla se haga un UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE se obtenga información si se hizo desde un SP y almacenar su nombre?

Comment: Que yo sepa no, porque `eventData()` que podría traer algo de info no aplica. Es posible que si utilizas alguna `dmv` o `sys.sysprocesses` y utilizando el `sql_handle` puedas conseguir algo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con:

```
OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
```

**OBJECT_NAME ( object_id [, database_id ] )** devuelve el nombre del objeto de la base de datos para los objetos de ámbito de esquema
y **@@PROCID** devuelve el identificador (Id.) de objeto del módulo Transact-SQL actual, que puede ser un SP, una función definida por el usuario o un trigger.